# My servlet returns null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I wrote the following form and servlet , hoping that the servlet would return the value of the text field from the form , but it returns **null** instead. What should be corrected ?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="theServlet">
    <input type="text" id="userName"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>



  public class theServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String username=request.getParameter("userName");

        response.setContentType("text/html");       
        PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();
        writer.println("<html>");
        writer.println("userName = "+ username);    
        writer.println("</html>");

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `name` attribute instead of `id` to send parameters to the server.

```html
<input type="text" id="userName" name="username" />
```

Comment: It ran , tnx for the help :)